# MySQL Workbench edit column without pk

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

How to edit columns if my table doesn't have aprimary key?
My way truncate the table and insert a record again... but this is not right.

Comment: single edit or multiple ?

Comment: What does column editing have to do with primary keys? Do you mean rows?

Comment: 1.single
2. yes, rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you temporarily add a primary key instead, e.g. add an auto inc column? After editing you can remove it. Better would be of course to have a permanent primary key.

Comment: yes, i tryed this was, but it's horrible like truncate the table and insert a record again